# Exception during SQL connection from Android test app in .Net

Tags: c#, android, sql, .net, azure

I created a simple code to test the connection to my Azure SQL DB. The code simply creates a new entry into the "Utenti" table.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("connection string");

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT utente (ID, password, nome_ut, image) VALUES (5, 'NorthWestern', 'ciao', 'aaa')";
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

This code works fine if I test the app on a Windows Machine, so I can see the new entry in my DB.

When I try the connection on Android, I receive the following exception:

> {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
> 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager' threw an
> exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type
> initializer for
> 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider' threw
> an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
> Configuration system failed to initialize --->
> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on
> this platform.   at
> System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean
> includeUserConfig)   at
> System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath,
> Boolean includeUserConfig)   at
> System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths()   at
> System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String
> configPath)   at
> System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
> at
> System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp()
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()   at
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()   at
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
> sectionName)   at
> System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStatistics.InitializeConfiguration(NameValueCollection
> config)   at
> System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStatistics..ctor(MemoryCache
> memoryCache, NameValueCollection config)   at
> System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.InitDisposableMembers(NameValueCollection
> config)   at
> System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Init(NameValueCollection config)
> at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache..ctor(String name,
> NameValueCollection config)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider..cctor()
> in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.cs:line
> 30   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager.SetDefaultAuthProviders(SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
> instance) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlAuthenticationProviderManager.cs:line
> 42   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager..cctor() in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netcore\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlAuthenticationProviderManager.NetCoreApp.cs:line
> 37   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
> MilestoneGP_app.MainPage.OnCounterClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> in
> C:\Users\pelli\source\repos\MilestoneGP_app\MilestoneGP_app\MainPage.xaml.cs:line
> 46   at
> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Button.Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.IButtonElement.PropagateUpClicked()
> in D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Button\Button.cs:line 275   at
> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ButtonElement.ElementClicked(VisualElement
> visualElement, IButtonElement ButtonElementManager) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Button\ButtonElement.cs:line 40
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Button.SendClicked() in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Button\Button.cs:line 250   at
> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Button.Microsoft.Maui.IButton.Clicked() in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Button\Button.cs:line 484   at
> Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler.OnClick(IButton button, View v)
> in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Button\ButtonHandler.Android.cs:line
> 148   at
> Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler.ButtonClickListener.OnClick(View
> v) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Button\ButtonHandler.Android.cs:line
> 169   at
> Android.Views.View.IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_(IntPtr
> jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_v) in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Android.Views.View.cs:line
> 2374   at
> Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(_JniMarshal_PPL_V
> callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0) in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line
> 125}

It's the first time I've tried to connect a DB to an Android application, so please consider all the mistakes I could make :)

I'm using .NET Maui 8.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide your connection string?

Comment: Here the connection string:
Server=tcp:milestonegp.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MilestoneGP;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={USER-ID};Password={PASSWORD};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;